# File indenting in Visual Studio on the MAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have seen some applications where the C# code is split among different files with each file holding a partial class.  From what I see it's possible to make these appear indented in Visual Studio on the Mac like in this example:

```
file1
   file1.data
   file1.commands
   file1.bindings
```

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this visual effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `<DependentUpon />` tag in your csproj file.

```
<Compile Include="file1.cs" />
<Compile Include="file1.data.cs">
  <DependentUpon>file1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="file1.commands.cs">
  <DependentUpon>file1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="file1. bindings.cs">
  <DependentUpon>file1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I don't believe there is a shortcut to do that in visual-studio unless you install an extension; you will have to manually edit a csproj in a text editor. Also, I don't think there are any plugins available for VS for Mac yet.

References:

1. [Nesting Files In Visual Studio](https://davefancher.com/2012/02/23/nesting-files-in-visual-studio/)
2. [Introducing File Nestor for Visual Studio](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MadsKristensen/Introducing-File-Nestor-for-Visual-Studio)

**EDIT 1**
Looks like there is a [nesting add-in](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/237)(beta) available for MonoDevelop - which in turn should be compatible with VS for Mac.